# Ion RangeSlider without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ion-range-slider

Is it possible to get a ion rangeslider without jQuery ?

The script below cause problems on my website with a part of the menu dedicated to users.

```
<!-jQuery->
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

I tried to remove the jQuery by following the reference below, but failed.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vanilla-rangeslider

Anyone kind enough to help me? Is there any way to get ion RangeSlider without Jquery?

Project: https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/ahsnfw80/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited project you have posted to use `vanilla` `js` only.
Here is the project [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zqZjTJd85GoGBJ9E)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works. All I did was upload the rangeslider.min.js file to my wordpress site and then declare it with <script src = "https://motustrength.it/wp-content/themes/astra-child/rangeslider.min. js "> </script>

After that I only had to change the initialization in the Js code, which in my case I changed to const js_range_mass = ionRangeSlider ('# range_mass', {etc ...
as suggested by your answer

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad that everything worked for you. Cheers